# mysql_fetch_row не работает. почему?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","1");
ini_set("display_startup_errors","1");
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
function engine_crypt ($password) {
    $salt=strlen($password).crc32($password);
    $sha1=sha1($salt.$password);
    $result=md5($sha1.$salt);
    return $result;
}

function engine_var ($var) {
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $newvar = str_replace("\n","",$var);
    $newvar = str_replace(";","&#59;",$newvar);
    $newvar = str_replace("%","&#37;",$newvar);
    $newvar = str_replace("'","&#39;",$newvar);
    $newvar = str_replace(",","&#44;",$newvar);
    $newvar = str_replace(".","&#46;",$newvar);
    $newvar = str_replace(":","&#58;",$newvar);
    $newvar = str_replace("`","&#96;",$newvar);
    return $newvar;
}
include 'includes/config.php';
$query="SELECT `id`,`nickname`,`status` FROM `users` WHERE `nickname`='".'buffon'."' and `password`='".engine_crypt('zblhepmz')."'";
$query_result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query_result) or die('DIED: '.mysql_error());
?>
```

query-запрос правильный 100% (в mysql выполняеться, и нормально возращает все)

(include 'includes/config.php'; подключение к базе)

выдает die, без какой либо ошибки. mysql_error() пуста. в чем соль? что проверить еще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так?

```
$query_result = mysql_query($query) or die('DIED: '.mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query_result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще то нужно делать mysql_query($query) or die('DIED: '.mysql_error());

Ошибка может вызываться из-за того что в выборке пусто. Т.е возвращает 0 рядов.

Comment: я же сказал "query-запрос правильный 100% (в mysql выполняеться, и нормально возращает все)"